# Const cast to non-pointer non-reference type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, const-cast

From [[expr.const.cast]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const.cast#3):

> For two similar types T1 and T2, a prvalue of type T1 may be
>   explicitly converted to the type T2 using a const_­cast if,
>   considering the cv-decompositions of both types, each *P*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>1</sup>  is the
>   same as  *P*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>2</sup> for all *i*. The result of a const_­cast refers to the
>   original entity.

It seems that const cast to non-pointer non-reference type is allowed. For example, the following function

```
void f(int a)
{
    const_cast<int>(a);
}
```

should be well-formed, since `int` and `int` are certainly similar types and have no *P*<sub>*i*</sub> in their cv-decompositions (thus the proposition that "each *P*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>1</sup>  is the same as  *P*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>2</sup> for all *i*" should be true).

However, both GCC and Clang reject the code above (see [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/iSXu_s)). The error messages are

Clang:

```
<source>: In function 'void f(int)':
<source>:3:22: error: invalid use of const_cast with type 'int', which is not a pointer, reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type
    3 |     const_cast<int>(a);
      |                      ^
```

GCC:

```
<source>: In function 'void f(int)':
<source>:3:5: error: invalid use of 'const_cast' with type 'int', which is not a pointer, reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type
    3 |     const_cast<int>(a);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I missing something or is it a compiler bug?

**UPDATE**: this doesn't work, either:

```
void f()
{
    const_cast<int>(int{});
}
```

Comment: The `a` parameter is not a *prvalue*, it is an *lvalue*, hence why the cast fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, please see my edited question

Comment: @RemyLebeau lvalue may be implicitly converted to prvalue

Comment: I looked at this yesterday as someone asked where lvalue conversion might occur for class types; if non-pointer types are similar then `T t; const_cast<T>(t)` would be an example (which would materialize a temporary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17 the types are not *similar* so the quoted text doesn't apply. And so this `const_cast` is not allowed because no `const_cast` is allowed unless explicitly permitted.

C++17 [conv.qual]/1:

> A *cv-decomposition* of a type `T` is a sequence of *cv<sub>i</sub>* and *P<sub>i</sub>* such that `T` is
>
> “cv<sub>0</sub> P<sub>0</sub> cv<sub>1</sub> P<sub>1</sub> ··· cv<sub>n-1</sub> P<sub>n-1</sub> cv<sub>n</sub> `U`” **for n > 0**,
>
> where each cv<sub>i</sub> is a set of cv-qualifiers (6.9.3), and each P<sub>i</sub> is “pointer to” (11.3.1), “pointer to member of class C<sub>i</sub> of type” (11.3.3), “array of N<sub>i</sub> ”, or “array of unknown bound of” (11.3.4). [...]

and then

> Two types T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> are similar if they have cv-decompositions with the same *n* such that corresponding P<sub>i</sub> components are the same and the types denoted by `U` are the same.

The requirement **n > 0** means that there must be cv<sub>0</sub> P<sub>0</sub>, i.e. at least one pointer in the type.

---

The latest C++20 draft changes **n > 0** to **n ≥ 0**,  as a result of [Issue 2051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1359r0.html#2051). But makes no change to the specification of `const_cast`. I couldn't say whether this is intentional or an oversight.

So it may be that C++20 will make your `const_cast` expressions well-defined , and compilers will have to catch up.

Comment: Interesting, [the current draft allows n=0](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.qual#1). It seems like there is a core language issue covering this.